# How do I make this HTML display as a table using CSS floats?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the following HTML display as a 3 column table using CSS.

```
<footer class="row">
  <div class="col1">
    Left Column
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    Middle Column
  </div>
  <div class="col3">
    Right Column
  </div>
  <div class="full-col">
    This should take up the width of 3 columns
  </div>
</footer>
```

This is what my CSS looks like:

```
.col1,.col2,.col3{
  width: 33.%;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.row{
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.col2{

margin: 0 auto;
}
.col1{
  float: left;
}
.col3{
  float: right;

}
.full-col{
  clear: both;
}
```

The problem is that the middle column in HTML is in the middle and right is below, so this happened:

[image: right column sitting below middle]

I can fix it by moving the middle column below (in the HTML), but isn't it possible to do this in CSS?

Comment: Try `box-sizing: border-box;` on `.col1,.col2,.col3{}`

Comment: https://gyazo.com/2a80599f03c348d119449953ab2db752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display:flex` to your row instead of making use of float it will align all the columns i.e col1,col2,col3 in a row fashion.

```css
.col1,.col2,.col3{
  height:30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  flex:1;
  
}

.row{
  background-color: #ccc;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
}

}
```

```html
<footer class="row">
<div class="col1"></div>
<div class="col2"></div>
<div class="col3"></div>
</footer>
```

**Solution with float and fixing the width size according to border:**

We set the width size of each cell = `(100% - 6px (which is the border size by all cells)) / 3`

```css
.col1,.col2,.col3{
  height:30px;
  text-align: center;
  width:calc((100% - 6px)/3);
  float:left;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.row{
  background-color: #ccc;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<footer class="row">
<div class="col1"></div>
<div class="col2"></div>
<div class="col3"></div>
<br style="clear: both;" />
</footer>
```

Comment: ty but i need to use floats

Comment: Well, the problem with your float is because of your borders you'll have to adjust your width everytime so that they stay inline.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/581baf0b09d41387914230fd1467659b idk why is happening i already declared now on row 100% and the other 3 33.3

Comment: @Pachi It is shifting because your margins are also taking space other than the width 33.33%.

Comment: @Pachi Updated the answer to include float too.

Comment: tyy worked, but on colum 2 is neccessary use float left? i thinked that i could do it with col 1 and 3 onlyy with float and the other should be naturall on the middle

Comment: Its better to keep it that way so the alignment doesn't mess up something else in the future, it won't affect anyway.